# Can PyTorch L-BFGS be used to optimize a complex parameter?

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, pytorch, gradient-descent, autograd

A brief description of my model:

- Consists of a single parameter `X` of dtype `ComplexDouble` and shape `(20, 20, 20, 3)`. For reference, this must be complex because I need to perform FFTs etc. on it
- `X` is used to compute a real scalar value, `Y` as the output
- The objective is to minimise the value of `Y` using autograd to optimize the value of `X`.

Simple gradient descent-based optimizers like `torch.optim.SGD` and `torch.optim.Adam` seem to work fine for this process. I would like to extend this to L-BFGS.

The problem is upon using

```
optimizer = optim.LBFGS(solver.parameters())

def closure():
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    Y = model.forward()
    Y.backward()
    return Y

for i in range(steps):
    optimizer.step(closure)
```

I get the error

```
File "xx\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\torch\optim\lbfgs.py", line 410, in step
    if gtd > -tolerance_change:
RuntimeError: "gt_cpu" not implemented for 'ComplexDouble'
```

According to the [source file](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/optim/lbfgs.py#L410), it's computing the directional derivative to be complex which disrupts the algorithm.

Is there any way to get L-BFGS working for my complex parameter (e.g. using an alternative library) or is this fundamentally impossible? I had some ideas about replacing these "faulty" dot products with something like `real(a.conj() * b))` but I wasn't sure whether that would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My intuition was correct. I replaced every occurence of `a.dot(b)` in the file with `torch.real(a.conj().dot(b))` and L-BFGS is working great!

Comment: What is the purpose of the complex conjugate here?